# Javascript upload and parse file on fly

Tags: javascript, csv, file-upload

Is it possible to upload file using

```
<input type="file">
```

and then parse it to javascript array without saving the file on server-side?
Could you advice any plugin to do it with csv (or any other) file type.

Is it good idea to do things such way without using back-end?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are talking about reading the contents of a file client-side, then use FileReader: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader.  If not, please clarify your question.

Comment: This is exactly what i'm looking for. Here is implementation of my problem: http://rohitrox.github.io/js_csv/

Comment: Then the code you will need to emulate can be found at https://github.com/RohitRox/js_csv/blob/master/index.html#L100.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Js code for upload csv and parse it client side and then plot them into console

```js
function uploadDealcsv () {}; 

  /*------ Method for read uploded csv file ------*/
  uploadDealcsv.prototype.getCsv = function(e) {
       
      let input = document.getElementById('dealCsv');
      input.addEventListener('change', function() {

        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {

            var myFile = this.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            
            reader.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
                
                let csvdata = e.target.result; 
                parseCsv.getParsecsvdata(csvdata); // calling function for parse csv data 
            });
            
            reader.readAsBinaryString(myFile);
        }
      });
    }

    /*------- Method for parse csv data and display --------------*/
    uploadDealcsv.prototype.getParsecsvdata = function(data) {

        let parsedata = [];

        let newLinebrk = data.split("\n");
        for(let i = 0; i < newLinebrk.length; i++) {

            parsedata.push(newLinebrk[i].split(","))
        }

        console.table(parsedata);
    }


  
  var parseCsv = new uploadDealcsv();
  parseCsv.getCsv();
```

```html
<input type="file" id="dealCsv"/>
```

Comment: Can also use reader.readAsText instead, if setting an encoding method is required.