# How to read csv headers

Tags: python, django

[image: So this is my uploading csv or excel file looks like.]

So this is my uploading csv or excel file looks like. So my question is, when a csv file is selected using "upload file" then I want to see the "headers" of csv file and display it before the "submit" button so that users can select which "header" they want. Only after that "submit" the csv file to upload.

views.py

```
if request.POST and request.FILES:
   csvfile = request.FILES['csv_file']
       if csvfile.name.endswith('.csv'):
          dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.readline())
          csvfile.open()
          readers = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',',dialect=dialect)
          header=False
          addhosts=set()
          for reader in readers:
            if header is True:
              name=reader[0]
              desc=reader[1]
              value=somemode.objects.create(name=name, desc=desc)
            header=True
       else:
          messages.error(request, "Uploaded file is not .csv" )
return HttpResponseRedirect('/someviews/')
```

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: I have coded to read the file once the file is uploaded but not before that.

Comment: @SharathNayak it's impossible to read a file without uploading it. Maybe you can create a middleware form and after upload you read the headers and let them choose.

Comment: You will need to write some Javascript to read the CSV file on the client side. See:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280901/javascript-upload-and-parse-file-on-fly/50578313

Comment: Will try writing js code. Thank you

Comment: If this is an admin operation rather than an any-user operation, it may be easier to write a custom management command: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-management-commands/

Answer (score 0):

So this is the answer without using javascript.

firstpopup.html

```
<div id="form">
    <form action="/someview1/{{id}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         #file upload part
    </form>   
</div>
```

secondpopup.html

```
<div id="form1">
    <form action="/someview2/{{id}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         #fields submit part
    </form>   
</div>
```

firstpopop.view

```
def someview1(request,id):
    args={}
    if request.POST and request.FILES:
        csvfile = request.FILES['csv_file']
        request.session['csv']=csvfile
        if csvfile.name.endswith('.csv'):
            dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.readline())
            csvfile.open()
            readers= csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            args['fieldnames'] = readers.fieldnames
    return render(request, 'firstpopup.html',args)
```

secondpopup.views

```
def someview2(request,id):
    csvfile = request.session['csv']
    title=request.POST['title']
    Desc=request.POST['desc']
    csvfile.open()
    readers= csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for reader in readers:
        ttl=reader[title]
        desc=reader[Desc]
        name=somemode.objects.create(Title=ttl,Description=desc)
    del request.session['csv']
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/someview3/'+id)
```