# Understanding local file uploads in web browsers

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I wasn't sure how to search for this questions - I'm trying to ensure that a file uploaded locally to a front-end application is not stored anywhere else, and removed when a user closes a web browser. I'm fairly new to web dev in general.

The small front-end web application accepts a CSV file via a file input `<input type="file" id="fileLoad" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">`. The code then parses the CSV data and basically only graphs the data and runs some error checking on the data.

The file is should not be uploaded anywhere, except for the local browser for plotting/error checking. What steps can I take to:

1. Confirm the data has not been cached or stored anywhere once the user closes the browser.
2. Demonstrate to the client requesting this application, that the data is not stored anywhere and remains local to the user's machine?

Comment: As long as you did not put this in a file upload form and submitted it, nor did you explicitly send any data to the server when you are processing the file in JavaScript, nothing will be sent to the server at all. "1." could be tricky, you'd have to know how browsers work internally, to be able to definitively say that the file or the data did not get cached anywhere on the client side; "2." can probably be proven to a reasonable extent by looking at the network traffic in browser dev tools.

Comment: Thanks for this. I guess even if "1" were true, is it likely the file data is still stored locally on the suer's machine, in the AppData folder? In terms of upload and parse, I was planning to use something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280901/javascript-upload-and-parse-file-on-fly). Seems to remain local.